# Pygame - How to blit an image quicker

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

Typing out `screen.blit(surface,(posx,posy))` over and over again for my games is very annoying. Is there a quicker way to do this?!

Answer (score 0):

Using a function can make it a lot shorter, for example

```
def blit(img,x,y):
   screen.blit(img, (round(x),round(y)))
```

To call it you would use something like:
`blit(mypicture,324,532)`

Comment: Consider that [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) truncate the number, while [`round()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) would round it up if the fraction part is `<=0.5`: `(round(x),round(y))`